# Create array from array to get totals

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following array users:

```
users = [
  {user: "1", times: 10, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 3},
  {user: "2", times: 15, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 5},
  {user: "1", times: 15, date: "2021-08-01", qty: 4},
  {user: "3", times: 25, date: "2021-08-01", qty: 3},
  {user: "2", times: 50, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 2},
  {user: "3", times: 30, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 3}
]
```

My task is to get totals (times * qty) by date for each users, following array:

```
result = [
  {
    date: "2021-07-31", 
    groups: [{user: "1", amt: 30}, {user: "2", amt: 75}, {user: "3", amt: ""}]
  },
  {
    date: "2021-08-01", 
    groups: [{user: "1", amt: 60}, {user: "2", amt: ""}, {user: "3", amt: 75}]
  },
  {
    date: "2021-08-02", 
    groups: [{user: "1", amt: ""}, {user: "2", amt: 100}, {user: "3", amt: 90}]
  }
]
```

Now i managed somehow to connect all users by date (in following snippet), but i'm struggling with solution of the task. I would like to get some hints, directions from You.

```js
const users = [
  {user: "1", times: 10, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 3},
  {user: "2", times: 15, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 5},
  {user: "1", times: 15, date: "2021-08-01", qty: 4},
  {user: "3", times: 25, date: "2021-08-01", qty: 3},
  {user: "2", times: 50, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 2},
  {user: "3", times: 30, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 3}
]

const result = [
  {
  date: "2021-07-31", 
  groups: [{user: "1", amt: 30}, {user: "2", amt: 75}, {user: "3", amt: ""}]
  },
  {
  date: "2021-08-01", 
  groups: [{user: "1", amt: 60}, {user: "2", amt: ""}, {user: "3", amt: 75}]
  },
  {
  date: "2021-08-02", 
  groups: [{user: "1", amt: ""}, {user: "2", amt: 100}, {user: "3", amt: 90}]
  }
]

let uniqueUsers = []
const uses = new Set()
let dates = []
const dats = new Set()
users.forEach(r => {
  let dat = {date: r.date}
  dats.add(JSON.stringify(dat))  
})
dats.forEach(d => {
  dates.push(JSON.parse(d))
})
users.forEach(r => {
  let dat = {user: r.user}
  uses.add(JSON.stringify(dat)) 
})
uses.forEach(d => {
  uniqueUsers.push(JSON.parse(d))
})
for (let i = 0; i < uniqueUsers.length; i++) {
  dates[i].groups = uniqueUsers
}
console.log(dates)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution gathers unique dates and users in first loop, than combines them together

```js
const users = [
    { user: "1", times: 10, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 3 },
    { user: "2", times: 15, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 5 },
    { user: "1", times: 15, date: "2021-08-01", qty: 4 },
    { user: "3", times: 25, date: "2021-08-01", qty: 3 },
    { user: "2", times: 50, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 2 },
    { user: "3", times: 30, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 3 }
]

const result = [
    {
        date: "2021-07-31",
        groups: [{ user: "1", amt: 30 }, { user: "2", amt: 75 }, { user: "3", amt: "" }]
    },
    {
        date: "2021-08-01",
        groups: [{ user: "1", amt: 60 }, { user: "2", amt: "" }, { user: "3", amt: 75 }]
    },
    {
        date: "2021-08-02",
        groups: [{ user: "1", amt: "" }, { user: "2", amt: 100 }, { user: "3", amt: 90 }]
    }
]

const res = [];
const date = {};
const userList = {};
users.forEach(u => {
    if (!date[u.date])
        date[u.date] = {};

    userList[u.user] = "";
    date[u.date][u.user] = u.qty * u.times;
});
for (d in date) {
    res.push({
        date: d, groups: Object.keys(userList).map(u => {
            return { user: u, amt: date[d][u] || "" }
        })
    });
};
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Array.reduce`

Logic

- From the list of `users`, generate an array that holds unique user id with empty quantity and hold it in `userQtyList`.
- Reduce the `users` array. Here group the `users` array depending on date and the list of users under individual date and store that in `result`.
- From the initial array `userQtyList` that holds the list of unique user and empty quantity, find the missing nodes for user against individual dates, from that, merge the missing nodes with existing groups and generate the array with all users. Then sort the groups array to generate the required list.

```js
const users = [
    { user: "1", times: 10, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 3 },
    { user: "2", times: 15, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 5 },
    { user: "1", times: 15, date: "2021-08-01", qty: 4 },
    { user: "3", times: 25, date: "2021-08-01", qty: 3 },
    { user: "2", times: 50, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 2 },
    { user: "3", times: 30, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 3 }
];

/* Generete the list of unique user id with empty quantity */
const userQtyList = users.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const node = acc.find((item) => item.user === curr.user);
    if (!node) {
        acc.push({
            user: curr.user,
            amt: ""
        })
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

/* Reduce the array to group the array with date and user id that exist for that date */
const result = users.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const node = acc.find((item) => item.date === curr.date);
    if(node) {
        node.groups.push({
            user: curr.user,
            amt: curr.times * curr.qty
        })
    } else {
        acc.push({
            date: curr.date,
            groups: [{
                user: curr.user,
                amt: curr.times * curr.qty
            }]
        })
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

/* Add the missing user node and sort them */
const updatedResult = result.map((node) => {
    const missingNodes = userQtyList.filter((usrQty) => !node.groups.find((nodeGrp) => nodeGrp.user === usrQty.user));
    node.groups = node.groups.concat(missingNodes);
    node.groups = node.groups.sort((a, b) => Number(a.user) - Number(b.user));
    return node;
})
console.log(updatedResult);
```

Comment: Users without amt are not in result, but thanks a lot for your time and effort, cheers

Comment: @NikolaPavicevic I have added the users without amount aswell to the group.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the task by using some utility like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/).

It's still a little ugly, but does the job. You can prettify it by extracting some functions (or using `lodash-fp` for a change).

This function also **adds amounts per user per day**. That's why I updated the input to demonstrate this behavior.

```js
const groupOrders = (orders) =>
  _.map(_.groupBy(orders, "date"), (orders, date) => ({
    date,
    groups: _.map(_.groupBy(orders, "user"), (orders, user) => ({
      user,
      amt: _.sumBy(orders, (order) => order.times * order.qty),
    })),
  }));

console.log(groupOrders([
  { user: "1", times: 10, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 3 },
  { user: "1", times: 15, date: "2021-07-31", qty: 5 },
  { user: "2", times: 50, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 2 },
  { user: "3", times: 30, date: "2021-08-02", qty: 3 },
]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It does not produce expected result as per `result` variable

Comment: You're right. I modified the input to show that results get accumulated per user per day.